# HTML form adding + button to generate more fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is part of an application form which should be modified:

[image: form]

I need to add something like `+` button in below of this row, after clicking this button It should add 1 more row (like above). Should be something like:

[image: more columns]

As you see in image above, after clicking red `+` button added new row. There should be ability to click `+` button (add new rows) as many times as user needs.

I know the way to play with visibility, but in this case I'll need to create like 100+ duplicates rows and hide them. Maybe there is any way to generate It via *Javascript* dynamically?

This is simplified part of an application form:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-style-9">
<ul id="personal-details">      
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="NameOfVessel">Name of Vessel</label>
                <input id="NameOfVessel" type="text" name="NameOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Name of Vessel" />   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="TypeOfVessel">Type of Vessel</label>
                <input id="TypeOfVessel" type="text" name="TypeOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of Vessel" />   
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="Flag">Flag</label>
                <input id="Flag" type="text" name="Flag" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Flag" /> 
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="DWT">DWT</label>
                <input id="DWT" type="text" name="DWT" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="DWT" />    
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>    
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="TypeOfMEkW">Type of ME/kW</label>
                <input id="TypeOfMEkW" type="text" name="TypeOfMEkW" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of ME/kW" />    
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>    
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="Rank">Position</label>
                <select id='Rank' name="Rank" class="field-style field-split25 align-left">
                    <option selected disabled value="0">Select position</option>
                    <option value="1">Master</option>
                    <option value="91">Ch. Officer Junior</option>
                    <option value="2">Ch.Officer</option>
                </select> 
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>    
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="SignOn">Sign on</label>
                <input id="SignOn" type="date" name="SignOn" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Sign on" />  
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>    
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="SignOff">Sign off</label>
                <input id="SignOff" type="date" name="SignOff" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Sign off" />   
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>    
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
                <input id="CompanyName" type="text" name="CompanyName" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Company Name" />   
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>           
</form>
</div>
```

I've created [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fa8b8Lw7/)

Comment: You can create the row using javascript when you click the **plus** button. You can google , you get good examples. But the basic example will be find at
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: you dont need visibility. you need The .append() method of jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery `.clone()` function. Change the `id` of your `ul` `"personal-details"` into `class` and clone it into your form when you click the add button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".add-row" ).click(function(){
      var $clone = $( "ul.personal-details" ).first().clone();
      $clone.append( "<button type='button' class='remove-row'>-</button>" );
      $clone.insertBefore( ".add-row" );
   });
  
   $( ".form-style-9" ).on("click", ".remove-row", function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
   });
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
.form-style-9{
    max-width: 450px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 6px solid #305A72;
}
body {
    background-color: #F7FDFF; 
}
.form-style-9 ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.form-style-9 ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1.25%;
   /* min-height: 58px;*/
}
.form-style-9 ul li  .field-style{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.form-style-9 ul li  .field-style:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #B0CFE0;
    border:1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split{
    width: 49%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split25{
   /* float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin-right: 1.25%;*/
 height: 40px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split25-4{
 /*float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin-right: 0;*/
 height: 40px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-full{
    width: 100%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input.align-left{
    /*float:left;*/
}
.form-style-9 ul li input.align-right{
    float:right;
}
.form-style-9 ul li textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="button"], 
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"] {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3985B1;
    background-color: #216288;
    border: 1px solid #17445E;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.submit-div {
 width: 100%;
 height: 32px;
 margin-top: 6%;
 padding-top: 6%;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
.submit-btn { 
 padding-top: 5%;
 display: block;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 width: 10%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="button"]:hover, 
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2D77A2 5%, #337DA8 100%);
    background-color: #28739E;
}


.formcol{
float: left;
padding: 2px;
} 
.formcol label {

font-weight: bold;
display:block;
} 
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.test {
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.test-select-label {
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.image-div {
 float:right;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-bottom:1.25%;
}
.image-upload {
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.image-preview {
  float:right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.test4 {
  float:left;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.test-label {  
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  padding:0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.test-label:first-child {  
  padding-left: 1.25%;
}
.test-label1 {  
  width: 23.2%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  padding:0px;
}
.removeRow{
height:auto;
width:auto;
max-width:12px;
max-height:12px;
}
.div-format-30 {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.25%;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.div-format-30 td{
  margin-top:20px;
  float:left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.25%;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.split33 {
  float:left;
  width: 28%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.split33-2 {
  float:left;
  width: 32.75%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.split33right {
  float:right;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.div-format {
  font-size:12px;
  float:left;
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 0.9%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  border: 1px solid #90C3D4;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
}

.div-format:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #F2FCFF;
}
.div-format:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #FAFEFF;
}
.div-format:nth-child(4) {
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.test4 {
  float:left;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.header {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: .25%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
#english {
 width:100%;
}
.resume-title {
 color: black;
 width: 20%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 position:absolute;
}
.container {
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;
}
.personal-details {
 padding-bottom:1.25%;
}
.container {
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align:center;
}
.application-form {
 position: absolute;
}
.personal-details{
  width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#personal-details2{
  width:60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
}
.personal-details > li{
  padding: 20px;
  width: 25%;
  border-top: 1px solid #90C3D4;
  border-right: 1px solid #90C3D4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #90C3D4;
  border-left: 0px solid #90C3D4;
}
.personal-details > li:first-child{
  padding: 20px;
  width: 25%;
  border-left: 1px solid #90C3D4;
}
.personal-details > li:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #F2FCFF;
}
.personal-details > li:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #FAFEFF;
}

.column{
  padding: 0;
}
.min-height {
 min-height: 40px;
 text-align:right;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.label-min-height {
 min-height: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
p {
 font-weight: bold;
}
hr.style18:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: ""; 
  height: 30px; 
  margin-top: -31px; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #90C3D4; 
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0; 
  border-radius: 20px; 
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-style-9">
<ul class="personal-details">  
 <li>
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="NameOfVessel">Name of Vessel</label>
    <input id="NameOfVessel" type="text" name="NameOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Name of Vessel" /> 
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="TypeOfVessel">Type of Vessel</label>
    <input id="TypeOfVessel" type="text" name="TypeOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of Vessel" /> 
   </li>   
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="Flag">Flag</label>
    <input id="Flag" type="text" name="Flag" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Flag" /> 
   </li>   
  </ul>
 </li>   
 <li>
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="DWT">DWT</label>
    <input id="DWT" type="text" name="DWT" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="DWT" /> 
   </li>  
  </ul>
 </li>   
 <li> 
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="TypeOfMEkW">Type of ME/kW</label>
    <input id="TypeOfMEkW" type="text" name="TypeOfMEkW" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of ME/kW" /> 
   </li> 
  </ul>
 </li>   
 <li> 
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="Rank">Position</label>
    <select id='Rank' name="Rank" class="field-style field-split25 align-left">
     <option selected disabled value="0">Select position</option>
     <option value="1">Master</option>
     <option value="91">Ch. Officer Junior</option>
     <option value="2">Ch.Officer</option>
    </select> 
   </li>  
  </ul>
 </li>   
 <li> 
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="SignOn">Sign on</label>
    <input id="SignOn" type="date" name="SignOn" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Sign on" /> 
   </li>  
  </ul>
 </li>   
 <li> 
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="SignOff">Sign off</label>
    <input id="SignOff" type="date" name="SignOff" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Sign off" /> 
   </li>  
  </ul>
 </li>   
 <li> 
  <ul class="column">   
   <li>
    <label for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
    <input id="CompanyName" type="text" name="CompanyName" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Company Name" /> 
   </li>  
  </ul>
 </li>  
</ul>
<button type="button" class="add-row">+</button> 
<div class="submit-div">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn" />
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, nice solution, but It a little bit different from my desired output. It cloning with labels, It should clone only text fields below. Is It possible to achieve that? Also there is possible to add ability to remove row, something like `X` button, in case if user  added too many rows?

Comment: Yes you can remove the labels but I think you probably need to change your structure and use HTML table for this.

Comment: Ok, about removing labels all right. Will be good with labels. But how about removing row if added too many?

Comment: You need to add a remove button in each row to remove it. Let me few minutes to update my answer for this.

Comment: Thanks. Also there is problem, after clicking `+` button, It generating new row in bottom of page (below submit button), It should clone inside the same `ul`

Comment: Why you don't use HTML table for this ? I think it would be more appropriate for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I couldn't achieve design like this with HTML table, too poor knowledge, that's why I'm using style like this.

Comment: Solved problem with appending close to correct place, just how about remove button?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle using jQuery 2.1.1 and an HTML table. You could try that. You could try this, althoug it doesn't have the same styling as your initial code.

[**Click here**](https://jsfiddle.net/soumyar/0653q73p/)

> jQuery Code

```
    $(function(){
    $('#addMore2').on('click', function() {
            var data = $("#tb2 tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb2");
            data.find("input").val('');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```